# Black hole vs Dark energy

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, black-holes, space-expansion

This is a follow-up question to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/717123/313823) answer.

The original question was whether there is a maximum size limit to a black hole in our universe.  The answer given was that if the event horizon coincided with the cosmic horizon, no valid metric solutions exist. (This is an interesting edge case for general relativity that I hadn't considered before).

My follow-up question is:
as our hypothetical black hole grew larger and larger, long before it approached the size of the cosmic horizon, when it is as big as galactic clusters, say, would the cosmological constant start to counteract the "structural integrity" of the black hole? Would the $\Lambda$ added up over the interior volume of the black hole cause space to (try to) expand inside the event horizon, partially counteracting gravity? Perhaps altering the size of the event horizon.

Has any study tried to (in a sense) superimpose the Schwartzchild and FLWR solutions like this?

Comment: The increasing density of negative energy "phantom" energy would eventually dissolve the black hole horizon, I think that coincides with the approach of the cosmic horizon. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/717062/is-there-a-maximum-mass-limit-for-black-holes

Comment: A Schwarzschild black hole embedded in a FLRW spacetime is described by the McVittie metric.

Comment: @BMF By definition, nothing “inside” a black hole can have any external effect. Thus your comment above is incorrect.

Comment: @safesphere you're right, this isn't my field. The electric charge of a black hole can change without anything "inside" expressing itself "outside", and same for the property of mass.