# Can a receding body due to the accelerated spacetime expansion be "rescued"?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, astrophysics, space-expansion, dark-energy

Once a body "crosses" the limit where dark energy wins over gravitational forces ([Is there a distance from a gravitational source where the influence of gravity and dark energy are balanced out?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/782760/is-there-a-distance-from-a-gravitational-source-where-the-influence-of-gravity-a)) would there be any way to make it return to the zone where gravity overwhelms the influence from dark energy?

For example, if a body is orbiting a massive point and begins to slowly recede from it due to the expansion of the universe, could some kind of slingshot effect caused by a passing external object make that body get closer to the source of gravity to the point that it gets "trapped" in the zone where gravity wins over dark energy and therefore does not recede forever?

Answer (score 1):

In GR, you can find any kind of setup you like, you just need the right initial conditions for the mass density and its derivatives. However, cosmology studies the universe as a whole, in an averaged out sense. It doesn't make sense to talk about specific configurations in this context, and the expansion belongs to this context. There is certainly no "recombination effect" in a cosmological sense when $dr^2$ shifts to $dr^2(1+\Delta)$.

Comment: what do you mean with there is certainly "no recombination effect"? @secr